# ios A tableview above a scroll view and the button on the scroll view cannot be tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` on my screen and there are some `UIButtons` on the scroll view.
I also have a `UITableView` which is above the scroll view, i.e. the tableview and the scrollview are overlapped.

Why I did this is because I want left and right swipe to flip pages of the scroll view and up/down swipe to show some text on the tableview.

This works fine except the button on the scroll view cannot be tapped. It seems that the tableview "absorbed" the tap event and it did not pass it to the button on the scrollview.

Is there someway to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This *could* be a solution but I'm not sure of it because from your question I can't understand your problem very well, you can try it but if it doesn't work we will try a different way. Maybe the problem is the arrangement of the UI elements in your Interface Builder/Storyboard. If I correctly understood your situation you have something like this:

[image]

To make to `UIButtons` clickable you have to be sure they're at the highest level of arrangement inside the `UIScrollView` since the `UITableView` could cover them and "absorb" [as you said] the touch input. So my suggestion is: arrange your UI elements following the blue arrow in the picture below, placing the `UIButtons` on top, in this way they'll be 100% clickable.

If I didn't understand your question could you please shoot a picture like the one I've posted so I can understand it better?